# Make Live paint group into single shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I recently followed [this tutorial](https://illustratorhow.com/make-pixel-art/) to create pixel art in Illustrator using a live paint group.

The difference between the example and mine is that mine is effectively all one colour. I want to export my picture as an SVG, however I've noticed that when I do this, it exports every “pixel” as a separate item.

Is there a way and can join all of these to effectively export as a single SVG shape?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I didn't watch the tutorial)

Note: This will **remove** the "live" aspect of the objects.

- Select the Live Paint Group.
- Click the `Expand` button in the **Control bar** across the top of the screen, if you haven't already done so.
- Click the `Unite` or `Merge` button on the **Pathfinder Panel** (`Window > pathfinder`).

You should then have 1 shape (which may be a compound shape).